i want to output the values on multiple headers depending on if the value is found in the list below the header
im on google sheets. so i want to output a set of words in a header, depending on if the number in a cell is found in the columns below the header. I also wanted it to output each header in a line break depending on if the number in a cell is in it. So if the number is found in columns A, G, and I it will output the header in those columns.
what i know how to do is this
=SUBSTITUTE(
TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), TRUE,
IF(COUNTIF(A2:A, G5), A$1, ""),
IF(COUNTIF(B2:B, G5), B$1, "")
),
", ", CHAR(10)
)
basically looks for the number in cell G5 in columns A and B, then outputs the header so A1 and B1. But I want to make it more dynamic because I'll be using it multiple times. I need help in making the formula work for multiple columns. like let's say ill be doing it in a table with 20 columns. how do i NOT do it manually per column?


A generalized representation for lets say 6 columns A-F and Cell_G5 has the search_criteria:
=join(char(10),ifna(filter(A1:F1,bycol(A2:F,lambda(Σ,xmatch(G5,Σ))))))


How about if I want to do use the formula in three different sheets (so 3 times basically), and each sheet has different number of columns? like sheet 1 has 8 columns, sheet 2 has 12 columns, sheet 3 has 6 columns. I can't use A1:F1 is there a way to just use one formula? tried switching the F1 and F in yours to Z but it didnt work

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q13PjHUp2_egqLhXtxAF1naEvqAHUH19I2hYliY7wS0/edit#gid=2100307022
here! so in cell K5 is where the current formula is, but its only until columns A and B. how do i make it from A to Z without manually adding the IF/COUNTIF for each column? yours was fine but it was only until F what if I had a table with 17 columns for example, then another with 10. is there a formula that i can use for that?

**the same above formula adapted in the test sheet

dude i love you thank you so much
